# Array to string conversion on view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't understand why I am experiencing an error with my variable $product_quantity while its $var_dump($product_quantity) gives the elements. The error points line 63 indicated in the code snippet. moreover It does not get $productInfo['image'] and $productInfo['url'].[check output of $var_dump($product_quantity) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqshJ.png)

```
<?php
$arr_products = unserialize($order['products']);

foreach($arr_products as $product_id => $product_quantity)
{
    $productInfo = modules::run('admin/ecommerce/products/getProductInfo', $product_id, true);
    var_dump($product_quantity);
    ?>
    <div style="word-break: break-all;">
        <div>
            <img src="<?= base_url('attachments/shop_images/'.$productInfo['image']) ?>" alt="Product" style="width:100px; margin-right:10px;" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?= base_url($productInfo['url']) ?>">
            <?= base_url($productInfo['url']) ?> 
        </a> 
        <--line 63-->
        <div style=" background-color: #f1f1f1; border-radius: 2px; padding: 2px 5px;"><b><?= lang('user_order_quantity') ?></b> <?= $product_quantity ?></div>

    </div>

    <hr>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: which line is giving you the array to string conversion error and what is the var_dump?

Comment: line 63 commented in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown by your `var_dump` your array is a multi-level associative array with the parent keys being `product_info` and `product_quantity`.

**I suspect if you change the line in question to `<?php echo $product_quantity['product_quantity']; ?>` you will no longer have an error.**

Also it seems like your `$product_quantity` contains your `product_info` as well so I'm not sure if this is entirely necessary `$productInfo = modules::run('admin/ecommerce/products/getProductInfo', $product_id, true);`
 (don't know your whole system so I might be wrong)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Kindly help me here too, i need to get the image and url from product_info but it cannot display as per code i have above.